# Calculus 2: Find Integral of Fraction with e and Square Roots

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm very stuck on the following problem:

Evaluate the integral

$$\int\frac{24e^\sqrt{3x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$

I set $u = \sqrt{3x}$ and tried to use substitution.  But I didn't get close to the right answer.

The right answer is: $8\sqrt{3}\ e^\sqrt{3x} + C$

A step through would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which operation are the `*` supposed to denote?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: sorry * is multiply

Comment: This is the correct substitution.  Please show us what you got from it.  Otherwise, how can we find your error?

Comment: Use $u = \sqrt{x}$ as substitution and write $\sqrt{3x}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\int\frac{24e^{\sqrt{3x}}}{2\sqrt x}dx$.

Let $u=\sqrt x$, thus $du=\frac 1{2\sqrt x}dx$.

$$S=\int 24e^{\sqrt x \sqrt 3}\times{\frac {dx}{2\sqrt x}}$$
$$S=\int 24e^{u\sqrt 3}du$$
$$S=24\times\frac{e^{u\sqrt3}}{\sqrt 3}+C$$
$$S=8\sqrt 3e^{\sqrt{3x}}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int\frac{24e^\sqrt{3x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=24\int e^\sqrt{3x}d(\sqrt{x})=\frac{24}{\sqrt{3}}\int e^\sqrt{3x}d(\sqrt{3x})=8\sqrt{3}e^\sqrt{3x}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is already a derivative in the integrand:
$$I=\int\frac{24e^\sqrt{3x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\dfrac {24}{\sqrt 3}\int\frac{e^\sqrt{3x}}{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt 3}dx$$
$$I=\dfrac {24}{\sqrt 3}\int\left ({e^\sqrt{3x}}\right )'dx$$
$$I=\dfrac {24}{\sqrt 3}{e^\sqrt{3x}}+C$$
$$I=8{\sqrt 3}{e^\sqrt{3x}}+C$$